# Bash execution issue with heroku

Tags: bash, heroku

I'm writing a bash script for deploy in heroku, but it always fails.

The script command is

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    set -- $line
    echo "processing $4"
    #Folder $1
    cd $1
    #Branch $2
    git checkout $2
    #Remote $3
    git push $3 $2
    #Heroku App Name $4
    echo "App name $4"
    heroku run rake db:migrate -a $4
    echo "restarting $4"
    heroku restart -a $4
    cd ..
    echo "DONE!"
done < "config.txt"
```

The error lines is the next.

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate -a $4
 heroku restart -a $4
```

Where $4 has the name of my app. The execution fail with an Internal Server Error.

But if I replace $4 for the App name it works.

I try with eval

```
eval "heroku run rake db:migrate -a $4"
```

Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

config.txt has just two lines.

```
testapp dev heroku_dev  testapp-dev
testapp master  heroku_dev  testapp-dev
```

Thanks so much for your support.

Bye.

Comment: In that loop all your commands are running with standard input attached to the `config.txt` file handle. If `heroku` tries to read from standard input that will likely confuse things. Does `heroku run rake db:migrate -a $4 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null`, etc. work?

Comment: The config.txt had a wrong encode for Unix. This file was build in windows. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

The config.txt had a wrong encode for Unix. This file was build in windows. My fault.